# Combining two existing annotation elements (PDFTron Net SDK)

Tags: c#, uwp, annotations, pdftron

I am trying to create a custom annotation element combining an arrow and a freetext box element. The Arrow element i would like it  to have its default behavior as originally assigned in the SDK, the freetext box though I would like to have a default size, predefined text in it and follow the arrow tail as soon as the arrow is moved or resized (selection, scaling transformation of the textbox I would like to disable it). Currently I have managed to draw an arrow with a free text element appearing on it's tail, but I am not aware of how I could make that free text element follow the arrow tail when its position changes and disable all its functionality (selection, scaling transformation, text input, etc...). Is there a way to group two existing annotation elements into one, or is  there another easier approach of creating an arrow with textbox in its' tail including predefined text? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As it is currently written, your question is incredibly hard to read and understand, and almost impossible to answer without seeing some of the code you have written. I'd recommend you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then come back and edit your question, to take account of the suggestions there.

Answer (score 1):

The code below shows how to add text to the default appearance that PDFNet will generate. Essentially you are decorating the default appearance.

The best thing to do is use our default appearance, and then overlay with your own content.

After calling `Annot.RefreshAppearance`, you would call something like the following.

```
static public void AddDecorations(Annots.Line line, PDFDoc doc)
{
ElementReader reader = new ElementReader();
ElementWriter writer = new ElementWriter();
ElementBuilder builder = new ElementBuilder();


writer.Begin(doc); // start new content stream


SDF.Obj old_app_stm = line.GetAppearance();
reader.Begin(old_app_stm);


Element element;
// isolate PDFNet default appearance in group
writer.WriteElement(builder.CreateGroupBegin());
while ((element = reader.Next()) != null)
{
    writer.WriteElement(element);
}
element = builder.CreateGroupEnd();
writer.WriteElement(element);


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Create matrix to position and rotate new text
Point start_pt = line.GetStartPoint();
Point end_pt = line.GetEndPoint();
double xDiff = end_pt.x - start_pt.x;
double yDiff = end_pt.y - start_pt.y;
double angle = Math.Atan2(yDiff, xDiff);
Matrix2D mtx = Matrix2D.RotationMatrix(-angle);
mtx.m_h = start_pt.x;
mtx.m_v = start_pt.y;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////


element = builder.CreateTextBegin(Font.Create(doc, Font.StandardType1Font.e_helvetica_bold), 8);
writer.WriteElement(element);
element = builder.CreateTextRun(String.Format("{0}", line.GetSDFObj().GetObjNum()));
element.SetTextMatrix(mtx);
writer.WriteElement(element);
Rect new_bbox = new Rect();
element.GetBBox(new_bbox);
element = builder.CreateTextEnd();
writer.WriteElement(element);

// update bounding boxes
Rect old_bbox = new Rect(old_app_stm.FindObj("BBox"));
old_bbox.Normalize(); // make sure x1,y1 is bottom left
new_bbox.Normalize();
new_bbox = new Rect(Math.Min(new_bbox.x1, old_bbox.x1), Math.Min(new_bbox.y1, old_bbox.y1), Math.Max(new_bbox.x2, old_bbox.x2), Math.Max(new_bbox.y2, old_bbox.y2));
SDF.Obj new_app_stm = writer.End();
new_app_stm.PutRect("BBox", new_bbox.x1, new_bbox.y1, new_bbox.x2, new_bbox.y2);
line.SetRect(new_bbox);

line.SetAppearance(new_app_stm);
}
```

In summary, you wrap the pre-existing drawing elements in a group, and then write your own new content. Then update the bounding box rectangle, and update the appearance stream and annotation bounding boxes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Ryan, that was very helpful. I have followed the suggestion of decorating a default appearence, and essentially I am also adding a rectangle in order to surround the text content at the end of the arrow. I would like ask if there is a capability of setting the color of the text added like defining the font and the font size.